# Using a Wii Nunchuck for data collection

Tags: arduino, wii, nunchuck, accelerometer, tutorial

Anyone got a good tutorial on using and Arduino to capture the Wii Nunchuck accelerometer data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Windmeadow Labs blog post titled ["Read wii nunchuck data into arduino"](http://www.windmeadow.com/node/42).

Comment: Website doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Todbot wrote a [tutorial](http://todbot.com/blog/2008/02/18/wiichuck-wii-nunchuck-adapter-available/) for this a while ago. He also made a small nunchuck-breadboard adapter so you wouldn't have to cut off the connector of your nunchuck to get to the wires. [Sparkfun.com](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9281) sells these.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched for wii nuNchuck arduino on Google and got about 90 000 hits, including this one: [Read wii nunchuck data into arduino](http://www.windmeadow.com/node/42) which may do what you want. Notice the second n in nunchuck not m (this may be why you weren't finding anything decent on Google et al).